# Invalid next compile error

Tags: ruby, rescue

I have a method that scans a URL for a website that contains an error:

```
def begin_vulnerability_check
  info("Checking if sites are vulnerable.")
  IO.read("#{PATH}/temp/SQL_sites_to_check.txt").each_line do |parse|
    Timeout::timeout(10) do
      parsing = Nokogiri::HTML(RestClient.get("#{parse.chomp}"))
      info("Parsing page for SQL syntax error: #{parse.chomp}")
      if parsing.css('html')[0].to_s[/You have an error in your SQL syntax/]
        successful = parse
        success("URL: #{parse.chomp} returned SQL syntax error, dumped to SQL_VULN.txt")
        File.open("#{PATH}/lib/SQL_VULN.txt", "a+"){|s| s.puts(parse)}
        sleep(1)
      else
        err("URL: #{parse.chomp} returned and error, dumped to non_exploitable.txt")
        File.open("#{PATH}/lib/non_exploitable.txt", "a+"){|s| s.puts(parse)}
        sleep(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

During testing I'm scanning through this list of URLs:

```
http://www.bible.com/subcat.php?id=2'
http://www.cidko.com/pro_con.php?id=3'
http://www.slavsandtars.com/about.php?id=25'
http://www.police.gov/content.php?id=275'
http://www.icdprague.org/index.php?id=10'
http://huawei.com/en/plugin.php?id=hwdownload'
https://huawei.com/en/plugin.php?id=unlock'
https://facebook.com/profile.php?id'
http://www.footballclub.com.au/index.php?id=43'
http://www.mesrs.gouv/index.php?id=1525'
```

I also have a rescue block that is suppose to catch the exception `Timeout::Error` and move to the next URL in the list:

```
begin
  begin_vulnerability_check
rescue Timeout::Error
   if Timeout::Error 
     warn("Page timed out, this is usually cause by the page returning a white page, or being non-existent, skipping.")
     next
  end
end
```

However while attempting to run this program, I get the following error:

```
whitewidow.rb:130: Invalid next
whitewidow.rb: compile error (SyntaxError)
```

Line 130:

```
rescue Timeout::Error
   if Timeout::Error 
     warn("Page timed out, this is usually cause by the page returning a white page, or being non-existent, skipping.")
     next #<= HERE
  end
end
```

My question being, am I using the `next` in the wrong sense? It seems to me like next would be, if this happens go to the next line, am I wrong for thinking like that? How can I refactor this to work?

Comment: You can use `next` to go to the iteration when iterating a `Enumerable`.

Comment: @Mischa would you be able to elaborate a little more?

Comment: By the way, what are you going to do when you find a site with a vulnerability?

Comment: It's how I make money. I have a CEH and notify the owners of the site, just tired of using other tools and wanted to make my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `next` to return from a block. You cannot use it outside a block like you're trying to do.

But you don't even need `next`, because when you rescue the timeout error the iteration will automatically continue with the next line. You just have to move the `rescue` inside the `each_line` iteration.

Your code should be something like this:

```
def begin_vulnerability_check
  IO.read("#{PATH}/temp/SQL_sites_to_check.txt").each_line do |parse|
    begin
      Timeout::timeout(10) do
        ...
      end
    rescue Timeout::Error
      # Will automatically continue with next line after this
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I'll mention you in the credits ;)

Comment: You can definitely use `next` outside of an enumeration. `next` is for blocks what `return` is for methods: it returns a value from a block. It's completely irrelevant whether that block is used for enumeration, starting a thread, lazy evaluation, closure, or even not used at all.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this.